# Alternative to ReportNG?

Tags: testng, test-report

[ReportNG](https://github.com/dwdyer/reportng) seems to be a commonly-used TestNG plugin among some of my colleagues, but it has effectively not been maintained since Sep 2, 2013.  Is there some alternative that has superseded it?

Comment: Check allure reporting

Answer (score 1):

You can use allure reports,  it is under active development and widely used
http://allure.qatools.ru

Answer (score 0):

I am using "sure-fire reports"

- Give a try, this "sure-fire" is also having good amount of support
- Generate emailable reports using some comman color codes like green & red
- Reports are in detail manner

Answer (score 0):

Try extentreports.
Here is an sample with c#

http://sqaplus.blogspot.com/2016/09/using-extentreports-with-mstest.html